# Symfony 4 : Request object change

Tags: symfony, events, symfony4

i'm working on Symfony 4.

I have a service:

```
    App\EventListener\EbayExceptionListener:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller }
    arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" , "@router" , "@session" ]
```

And here is my listener :

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\Ebay;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class EbayExceptionListener
{
    private $repository;
    private $router;
    private $session;
    private $redirectName = 'home';

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, Router $router, Session $session)
    {
        $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Ebay::class);
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    //Check if an eBay entity exist in the database, if not redirect to the form to create the eBay entity
    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $ebay = $this->repository->findOneBy(['name' => 'Ebay']);
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $routeName = $request->get('_route');
        dump($routeName);
        if ($routeName != "home" AND $ebay == null) {
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Please provide information for Ebay form');
            return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate($this->redirectName));
        }
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'HomeController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

I have a problem with the var `$routeName` inside my Listener, in fact the value of this variable should be the name of the current route. But when I use the `dump($routeName)`

I have 2 results : "_wdt" and "home"

[image]

I don't know why the `$request` parameters are not the same when my listener is executed and after the page has been generated.
Because I have no page call "_wdt" it supposed to be "home".
Did I do something wrong ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The _wdt is what the profile bar at the bottom of the screen uses to get debug information.  What is happening is that the home route returns a response then a bit of javascript is used to call the _wdt route.  And you are seeing both.  This will only happen in development mode so just add a check to ignore _wdt.  You should also be aware that it is possible to generate sub-requests which basically nests routes.  So you should check that the request is the master request as well.

Comment: Hi Cerad thank for your answer, but I didn't get how to solve my problem. What do you mean by "add a check to ignore _wdt" ?

Comment: if ($routeName === '_wdt') return;

Comment: Thank to Cerad I could find my answer in htis post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48074428/symfony-4-ignore-kernel-events-coming-from-debug-toolbar

Comment: Nothing says thanks like an upvote.